# Эквивалент $(document).on('click') для android?

Tags: android, android-on-click

Можно ли в android установить обработчик события до того как элементы появятся? Например поставить `OnClickListener` на контейнер-обертку, и слушать там все клики, т.е. в нем всегда будет проверяться id элемента по которому кликнули.
Например в javascript так можно:

```
$(document.body).on('click','#myElem',handler)
```

Тут обработчик вешается на узел `body` веб-страницы, он будет срабатывать по клику на элемент с `id` равным `myElem`, при этом не важно когда такой элемент был создан, до того как был установлен обработчик или после. 
Можно ли подобное сделать в android?

Comment: видимо нет, нельзя привязать интерфейс к объекту, который не существует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слушатель конечно можно поставить на контейнер/обертку, главное чтобы эти клики передавались в контейнер. В контейнере всегда можно ветвиться по `id` клика:

```
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(View view) {
     switch(view.getId()) {
        //blah-blah
     }
});
```

только надо озаботиться тем, чтобы родительский контейнер (`Layout`) - имел атрибут `android:descendantFocusability=0`, это гарантирует, что родитель будет получать фокус перед своими потомками.

Comment: Вообще то я хрень написал - `id` будет всегда `id` родителя :) - подумаю еще как это можно реализовать...

Comment: грубо говоря, как-то нужно установить обработчик на все что внутри, и не важно когда оно появилось, до или после установки слушателя на родителя. В  javascript это предусмотрено на нативном уровне. Задался вопросом, можно ли замутить подобное в Android...

Comment: JavaScript это же интерпретатор, там можно и не такие выверты ставить...